# Add clickable link to admin page List_view

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add a clickable link to admin list_view for a specific app that will redirect me to a html file i created, I have created a view.py like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def transaction_print(request, transaction_id):
    transaction = Transaction.objects.get(id=transaction_id)

    return render(request, 'report.html', {'transaction': transaction})
```

and my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.transaction_print, name='transaction_print'),
    path('transaction/<int:transaction_id>/', views.transaction_print, name='transaction_print'),
]
```

I created the report.html at (root_dir/calculator/templates/report.html)

Now im not sure how to make a method at models.py to return maybe my views as a link to be add to list_view, or what is the best approach to achieving that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a mistake in your formulation.
From what you describe, you want to add a button on the change_view.

To do so, within your app template folder, create a file `extended_changeform.html`

in that file:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% block object-tools-items %}

<li><a href="{% url 'transaction_print' original.id %}" class="historylink">My button label</a>
</li>

{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

and in the admin class where you want to have the buttons:

```
class TransactionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "extended_changeform.html"
```